# Facebook doesn't ask permissions of users in my iPhone app

Tags: facebook, permissions, facebook-ios-sdk

I have an iPhone app using Facebook connect. When I test it on the iPhone simulator, because I don't have facebook application installed on the simulator. It runs the facebook webview and ask me permissions and everything works fine.

However, when I try it on my iPhone device, I have the facebook application and it runs my app but doesn't ask me permissions for my app. Then I get facebook didnotlogin.

Anyone know what is the problem? I probably missed something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bundle id for native IOS wasn't correct.

Answer (score 0):

i think may be you are using the older version of FB connect if not using the oath then use the new version of fb connect or check out the web view error log you can get some error log from there .

Comment: I found the solution one minute ago. My bundle id for native IOS wasn't correct.